# How to sort array having numbers as string in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [best way to sort NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361207/best-way-to-sort-nsarray)
>   [Sort an array with special characters - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492379/sort-an-array-with-special-characters-iphone)

Hello,
I have array in which i have numbers stored as string.
How to sort this array in acsending order?

Comment: already discussed in this forum <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492379/sort-an-array-with-special-characters-iphone>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = nil;
sortedArray = [oldArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:sortArray context:NULL];

NSInteger intSort(id num1, id num2, void *context) {

    // OR: float n1 = [num1 floatValue]; etc.

    int n1 = [num1 intValue];
    int n2 = [num2 intValue];
    if (n1 < n2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if (n1 > n2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```