# comparing NSStrings with Ä,Ö,Ü

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, diacritics

I am facing a weird problem.
I have a UITextField and an NSString which I want to compare using the isEqualtoString method.
As long as the Strings don't include German Umlaute such as Ä,Ö,Ü everything works fine but if they do it doesn't work anymore.
NSLog gives out the Umlaute-Strings correctly.

```
 NSLog([currentAnswer lowercaseString]);
 NSLog([[self.antwortTextField text]lowercaseString]);

if ([[currentAnswer lowercaseString] isEqualToString:[[self.antwortTextField text]lowercaseString]]) {......}
```

Do I have to format the Strings somehow? This problem is driving me insane!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort an array with special characters - iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492379/sort-an-array-with-special-characters-iphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an advanced `NSString` comparison method, such as:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)aString
                      options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask
                        range:(NSRange)range
                       locale:(id)locale
```

and then specify advanced options. Specific options you may be interested in:

- `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch`
- `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch`
- `NSWidthInsensitiveSearch`

Comment: sorry I am relatively new to Objective-C. How would I do that? I have absolutely no clue why it doesn't work in the first place. It's not like German is an ancient language or anything ;-)

Comment: perhaps `bool isEqual = NSOrderedSame == [str1 compare:str2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch];`, or some combination of options. the reason may be the language, or it may be locale, or encoding or…

Comment: Actually, the main thing is you want to use any of the `-compare...` methods without `NSLiteralSearch`.  The other options can be useful for other purposes.  `-isEqual:` and `-isEqualToString:` both use `NSLiteralSearch` which means that two different representations of the same letter compare differently.  For example, 'Ä' can be either U+00C4 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS) or U+0041 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A) followed by U+0308 (COMBINING DIAERESIS).  With a literal compare, those are different; for a non-literal compare, the same.